# Sails js bcrypt installation

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js, npm-install

Can  anyone tell why I'm having this error when I'm trying to install bcrypt on windows 10?

[image]

Comment: Can you paste your log instead of screen-shot?

Comment: im sorry, i dont have it right now, you cant see it dont you?

Comment: You also need python and [node-gyp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp) installed globally for installing bcrypt. Also try [bcrypt-nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-nodejs) in case bcrypt causes too many problems in installing it seems more stable for windows env and provides same functionality.

Comment: i think that too, but you how i solve the problem? changing my wifi pw... WTF?, i created 5 project without problems no more

Comment: do you have a `package-lock.json` in your project? Ohh and btw what's with changing your wifi pw :D

Comment: yes, i dont know why, whys that ?. I dont undestand the relation either...

Comment: delete it and try installing bcrypt again, for information on that file check [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json), I am not too sure either but somehow it might have been corrupted

Comment: before change the pw, i did that 312371237 times, this error is really extrange, because im only change the wifi pw, and im working great

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162819/discussion-between-tgw-and-osmelg).

Comment: i cant enter to it, can we speak via whatsapp?

Comment: Oh what I asked in chat was why do you need to change pw, about WhatsApp it's pretty difficult to share links and all

Comment: ok, send me via private your phone number to talk in whatsapp

Comment: Hehe okay but where do I send it?

Comment: Check please :)